# Argument 'appController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to fix this issue since 2 days but nothing worked.

Here is my index.html

```
<!--Js Files-->  
    <script src="js/supervisorChromeApp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/api/api.js"></script>

    <script src="js/services/supervisorApiService.js"</script>

    <script src="js/controller/appController.js"></script>
```

supervisorChromeApp.js

```
var supervisorChromeApp = angular
    .module('supervisorChromeApp', ['ngRoute'], function($provide) {

    })
;
```

supervisorApiService.js

```
    supervisorChromeApp.service('supervisorApiService',[function(){ 
    console.log('service loaded');  

}]);
```

appController.js

```
supervisorChromeApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location','supervisorApiService',
    function($scope, 
        $http,
        $location,
        supervisorApiService) {

    console.log("Controller loaded");
}]);
```

But I am getting this error:

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'appController' is not a function, got undefined`

Can someone please help me with this?
PS: This is a chrome extension app if it matters.

Comment: Are you not using text editor or ide? Just wasted 2 days. You could have build the extension in 2 days :)

Comment: Yeah right! Somehow dint notice it! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed **`supervisorApiService`**,

Change

**From**

```
  <script src="js/services/supervisorApiService.js"</script>
```

To

```
  <script src="js/services/supervisorApiService.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are so Right!!I have wasted 2 days on this.THank you so much.

Comment: But do you have any idea why it is throwing "appController" is not function error?Shouldn't it throw something like supervisorApiService not defined?